# Install of Ubuntu 20.04 but boots into UEFI shell

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, live-usb, bios

I have used the ubuntu 20.04 live usb iso **ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso** to install Ubuntu 20.04 on a Captec server.

I create a / and a /home partition on the NVME using the installer and the the installation process runs smoothly. It asks me to remove the usb installer disk and press  to reboot.

Upon booting it comes up with this screen:

```
PXE-E6: Media test failure, check cable
PXE-M0F: Exiting Intel Boot Agent.
```

It remains on the above screen for a short while then tries to boot into the UEFI Shell. Below is a screenshot of this screen:

[image]

The boot order in the BIOS is set to boot from the usb stick first and then the internal HD. What I have noticed is that it doesn't seem to show the NVME like it would normally in the BIOS. Just a generic HD is selectable. The BIOS boot option is set to from both Legacy as well as UEFI.

Not sure what else could be causing the machine not to boot from the NVME.

Comment: try booting into the live USB again and screenshotting gparted and show us

Comment: Many NVMe devices need firmware updates, even new ones. And UEFI often needs update. If you installed in UEFI boot mode, often better to have UEFI set to UEFI only. My system (Asus) only boots in UEFI mode with UEFI only, not UEFI or Legacy.